# how to replace array object in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
if(_list.length != 0){
      var shape;
      var shapeCount;
      var shapeCaratCount;
      var shapeTotalAmount;
      var details = new Map();
      var temp = [Map()];

      for(int l = 0 ; l <= _list.length; l++){
        var list = _list[l];
        if(temp.contains(list.shape)){
          shapeCount += 1;
          shapeCaratCount = shapeCaratCount + list.carat;
          shapeTotalAmount = shapeTotalAmount + list.totalAmount;

          details['Shape'] = list.shape;
          details['pcs_count'] = shapeCount;
          details['Carat_Count'] = shapeCaratCount;
          details['total_amount'] = shapeTotalAmount;
          print(details);
          temp.add(details);
        }else{
          shapeCount = 0;
          //shapeCaratCount = shapeCaratCount + list.carat;
          shapeCaratCount = list.carat;
          shapeTotalAmount = list.totalAmount;

          details['Shape'] = list.shape;
          details['pcs_count'] = shapeCount;
          details['Carat_Count'] = shapeCaratCount.toString();
          details['total_amount'] = shapeTotalAmount.toString();
          print(details);

          temp.add(details);
        }
      }

    }
```

I want to replace array object of `temp` dictionary array.

so if any know how to do this please help i am new at flutter

this is my code please if any difficulty. please ask.

Comment: I believe you are adding data to your Map temp. Please let me know where are you facing the problem?

Comment: Instead of `temp.add(details)` wouldn't you just write `temp[0] = details`?

Comment: ok let me try @Richard Heap

Comment: sorry my friend i am getting error with `temp[0] = details`

This is my error

`
E/flutter ( 4537): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]=' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 4537): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 4537): Tried calling: []=(1, "RD")
` @RichardHeap

Comment: Wherever you are calling that, `temp` is null. Add some debugging print statements to ascertain when temp was initialised, etc.

Comment: thank u for your help